# about virtual machine macos

Tags: windows, mac, virtual-machine, xcode

so I have windows and i need to use xcode to develop an app on ios, therefore i need to download macos on my computer.
my questions is:
1-will it slow my computer since it require downloading xcode and i think it uses 10 gb, my computer is 255 ssd.
2-how can i download it?
3-i want to use windows and macos at the same time, can i do that?
4-do you recommend me to do it?

thank you in advance!

Comment: X-Code runs on macOS only. It is also against the license to virtualize macOS on anything but Apple hardware.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the use of macOS on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## when using a virtual machine:

### 1: performance impact depends on your computer's specs and the settings/allotments you give to the virtual machine.

for example, if your PC is Windows 10 with high-end everything, you'll be able to give the guest (your VM) a lot more than if you only had a mid- to low-end laptop running Windows 7.

### 2: macOS ISOs aren't available publicly because Apple is very picky and protective of their property and software.

there's a way to dump a macOS `.dmg` image if you own a Mac, but if you owned a Mac you wouldn't need a virtual machine. however, installing macOS onto a system--virtual or not--that is not a Mac is usually called "hackintosh" and is generally frowned on from all i can find.

### 3: running a hackintosh system is generally difficult in setup and use, is unstable, and likely will not let you run a good portion of Apple software.

## when using your primary system:

### don't. see point three above.

as explained in point 3, hackintosh systems are unstable at best and will likely have Apple metaphorically knocking at your door every time you try to use anything Apple related. this is all not to mention to setup required to actually make it even close to work can brick your system if done even a sliver incorrectly.

you'd be better off just trying to get an actual Mac system; a new Mac Mini is ~$700.